# How To Set Up Different Quantity Of Products Per Magento 2 Store View

Tags: module, customize

How To Set Up Different Quantity Of Products Per Magento 2 Store View :

I have same product but different quantity for the this product switch store view
(FR / Suisse ) , For the Price i have found a extension but for the quantity ther's none

Version : 2.3.5 (Magento) , it's globaly in default => Store View

Comment: Btw it's the version Open source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Store View MSI Sales Channel extension. It allows to assign stocks to store views. Additionally, MSI Product Sources Configuration extension (which could be found on the same website) allows to define backorders and other inventory options for each source.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.3, MSI (MultiSource Inventory ) is introduced but as per [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.0OpenSource.html) that are available on the website level not on the store level.

to manage inventory on store-level you would need 3rd party warehousing extension, you can check one of the following extension :

1 -  [Amasty multi warehouse inventory](https://amasty.com/multi-warehouse-inventory-for-magento-2.html)

2 - [AITOC Multi-Location Inventory](https://www.aitoc.com/magentomods-multi-location-inventory.html)

These are a few which you can use for your site to multi-stock/warehousing.

Answer (score 0):

Change quantity attribute scope to store view.

GO to Stores > Product.

Find quantity_and_stock_status attribute_code and change the scope to Store View.

Greetings!

Comment: The quantity still Global , when i change a quantity in store view it change automaticly in the other store view

Comment: @OmarSadky select all products and choose update attributes on drop down list, also try to remove qty from the Default attribute Set, and add it again.

Comment: Hello , I have change quantity_and_stock_status in Store > Product globaly to store view then i have flush magento cach , after that i have go to store > attribute set i cant delete quantity_and_stock_status i have change only the position , last step when i wanna creat a new product the qantity style Global

Comment: thanks for your help , what you have say it's logique but the Quantity
[Globaly]

Comment: hi, did it worked to you?

Comment: no didnt work style global